# Using MySqlHook, how to output query results to string

Tags: python, sql, airflow

I am using My_Sql_Hook to get a connection to my test-db and I want to save the output of a query to a variable as a string. Is it possible to use something similar to the fetchall() function for My_Sql_Hook?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've access to the [`get_cursor`](https://github.com/apache/airflow/blob/master/airflow/hooks/dbapi_hook.py#L226-L230) method (*from [`DbapiHook`](https://github.com/apache/airflow/blob/master/airflow/hooks/dbapi_hook.py#L45-L350)*) on the hook object, which will return the underlying `Cursor` object for a connection; you can assume that object to match the [DBAPI](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0249/).